# Vertical Gestures Recognition on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How can i add vertical (Up and down) `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on `UITableView`. I can do left and right `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` but on vertical the table scrolls. I need to scroll as well and recognize gesture too. How this would be possible?

Comment: So you want to detect table scroll right?

Comment: No i don't need to detect scroll the thing is whien table is scrolled i want gesture recognizer to tell me that the swipe is at a point then  i want to call some method

Comment: Does your method is screen point specific?

Comment: I need to call a method when swipe reaches a point in screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will help you.

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeAction:)];
        swipeGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
        swipeGesture.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown);

        [mylabel addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
```

and add this method :

```
- (void) swipeAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeGesture {
   // action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A UITableView's delegate is also a [scroll view delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).  If you implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` in your delegate, you will be notified when the table scrolls.